# How to write output of a map reduce job directly to distributed cache so that it is passed to another job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am currently practising Map-reduce (Hadoop 2.2) and need your help on one of the concepts.

I have a use case which I want to complete using two jobs. I want output of job1 to be written to a Distributed cache and this is passed as input to second job.

Basically I want to avoid writing the output of first job to a file, causing overhead.

### Use case Input :

Songs file -

### | Id |   Song  |  Type  |

|s1 | song1 |  Classical | 
|s2 | song2 |  Jazz |
|s2 | song3 |  Classical |
.

User rating file -

### | User_Id |  Song_Id |  Rating |

| u1    |  s1   |      7      |
| u2    |  s2   |      5      |
| u3    |  s2   |      9      |
| u4    |  s1   |      7      |
| u5    |  s5   |      5      |
| u6    |  s1   |      9      |

**Note**: Both these files contains very large data.

### Usecase description:

Find the average rating of each song of type classical.

The actual/intended solution I have come up is that I will use two chained jobs.
 1.Job1 : It will get all the ids of classical songs and add to distribute cache

2.Job2 : Mapper in the second job filters the rating of classical songs based on the values in the cache. 
          Reducer will calculate the average rating of each song.

I searched on web to see if we can write the output of job directly to distributed cache, but was unable to find useful information.

I have found similar question on stackoverflow:

```
"How to directly send the output of a mapper-reducer to a another mapper-reducer without
 saving the output into the hdfs"
```

The solution for this is to use 'SequenceFileOutputFormat'.

However in my case I want all the song ids to be available to each mapper in second job. So I think the above solution will not work in my case.

The alternate approach I want to go with is to run the first job, which finds the ids of Classical songs and write the output (song ids) to a file and create a new job and add the song ids output file to second job's cache. Please advise.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Distributed cache is nothing more than a file copy, so either way it will write the file and copy it to all nodes afterwards. You gain nothing. Better write to HDFS and use it as input to the next job.

Comment: Hi John got any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can update intermediate results to ***[MemCached](http://memcached.org/)*** if eah record has less size <1mb

Answer (score 0):

Follow second approach.

1. First Job will write output to file system.
2. Second Job will pass the required file to all nodes by using Job API instead of `DistributedCache` API, which has been deprecated.

Have a look at new [Job](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html) API for methods like

```
addCacheFile(URI uri)
getCacheFiles()
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

An approach can be load the output(s) of first job in distributed cache, then launch the second job.

```
//CONFIGURATION

Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "Reading from distributed cache and etc.");
job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

////////////
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(getConf());

/*
 * if you have, for example, a map only job, 
 * that "something" could be "part-"
 */
FileStatus[] fileList = fs.listStatus(PATH OF FIRST JOB OUTPUT, 
                           new PathFilter(){
                                 @Override public boolean accept(Path path){
                                        return path.getName().contains("SOMETHING");
                                 } 
                            } );

for(int i=0; i < fileList.length; i++){ 
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(fileList[i].getPath().toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
}

//other parameters
```

Mapper:

```
//in mapper

@Override
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //SOME STRUCT TO STORE VALUES READ (arrayList, HashMap..... whatever)
    Object store = null;

    try{
        Path[] fileCached = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());

        if(fileCached != null && fileCached.length > 0) {
             for(Path file : fileCached) {
                readFile(file);
                }
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception in mapper setup: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

private void readFile(Path filePath) {

    try{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath.toString()));
        String line = null;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            //reading line by line that file and updating our struct store
            //....

        } //end while (cycling over lines in file)

        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception while reading file: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
} //end readFile method
```

Now in the map phase, you have the files passed as input to the job AND the values you needed stored in the struct `store`.

My answer comes from [How to use a MapReduce output in Distributed Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230251/4949261).