# How to use a MapReduce output in Distributed Cache

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

Lets say i have a MapReduce Job which is creating an output file `part-00000` and there is one more job running after the completion of this job.

How can i use the output file of the first job in the Distributed cache for the second job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below steps might help you,

- Pass the first job's output directory path to the Second job's Driver
  class.
- Use Path Filter to list files starts with `part-*`. Refer the below code snippet for your second job driver class,

  ```
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
      FileStatus[] fileList = fs.listStatus(new Path("1st job o/p path") , 
                                 new PathFilter(){
                                       @Override public boolean accept(Path path){
                                              return path.getName().startsWith("part-");
                                       } 
                                  } );
  ```
- Iterate over every `part-*` file and add it to distribute cache.

  ```
      for(int i=0; i < fileList.length;i++){ 
               DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(fileList[i].getPath().toUri()));
      }
  ```